# UIVideoEditorController crashes on iOS 7 if video maximum duration is set

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uivideoeditorcontroller

As the title states, an instance of UIVideoEditorController in an iOS 7 device causes a crash when you set the property videoMaximumDuration. This is the error that is logged in the console:

**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextView initWithFrame:textContainer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"**

Any ideas why this is happening? This works fine in iOS 6.

Comment: We're receiving the same error, investigating it now. Will let you know if we find anything.

Comment: Awesome. It's nice to know that we're not the only one experiencing this.

Comment: It appears that if we rebuild the App with the latest version of Xcode and latest iOS SDK that it no longer crashes on iOS 7, but will still crash on iOS 6. For now we've eliminated the ability to select a pre-recorded video on iOS 6 devices.

Comment: @jessecurry So you're restricting your app to edit videos that were only recorded from an iOS 7 device?

Comment: We're allowing users on iOS 7 to select videos from the camera roll, but only allowing iOS 6 users to shoot new video. We weren't seeing the crash on iOS 7, so we figured that this work around was the best option.

Comment: This happens for me as well. Apps built with iOS 6.x SDK cause a crash on iOS 7 when max duration is set. Running on iOS 6 it works, building with 7 SDK fixes it, but I can't use the 7 SDK as it messes with the rest of the app… Did you figure this out?

Comment: Our workaround was that we just showed an **alert** right after the trimming process finishes if the video is longer than the maximum duration.